# How do I do a nested case with this example?

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, case-when

I need to put a case around the below case to check if any of them = 'UNRESTICTED' which is when I do something

```
Select 
UPPER(CASE table.productnames 
    WHEN 'product1' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name
    WHEN 'product2' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT2_name
    WHEN 'product3' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT3_name 
    WHEN 'product4' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT4_name
    WHEN 'product5' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT5_name
    WHEN 'product6' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT6_name
    WHEN 'product7' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT7_name
    WHEN 'product8' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT8_name
    WHEN 'product9' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT9_name
    END)
```

I have tried

`WHEN 'product1' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name WHEN 'UNRESTRICTED' THEN 'NEWNAME'`

for each line but there must be a way that I can use a nested case to allow it to check for all the possible product names and check if they equal 'UNRESTRICTED' or is this not possible due to each product is a different field in the table?

Comment: Do you mean if table.productnames = 'UNRESTRICTED' THEN 'NEWNAME' ? if so then just add one more line when 'UNRESTRICTED' THEN 'NEWNAME' why you are adding for each line !

Comment: No sorry a bit of confusion here , the thing that returns 'UNRESTRICTED' is the 'THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name' and thats what I want to change if TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name = unresticted change it to = high...Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Not sure of your requirement.  Could you use REPLACE() on each line to change 'UNRESTRICTED' to 'NEWNAME'?

Comment: In the above case BenYeomans, you can proceed like                 CASE table.productnames 
    WHEN 'product1' THEN (Case When TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name ='unresticted' Then 'High' else 'whatever' End). but you need to write it for each line because for each line your product differs.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks @ram_sql

Comment: and yeah sorry @TabAlleman replace() would have worked fine for this, was just wondering if I could do it with a case :)

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, you could just do a single REPLACE() around your entire CASE statement, instead of one on each line.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did in the end , cheers @TabAlleman. Put it as an answer if you like and I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Select 
REPLACE(UPPER(CASE table.productnames 
    WHEN 'product1' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name
    WHEN 'product2' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT2_name
    WHEN 'product3' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT3_name 
    WHEN 'product4' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT4_name
    WHEN 'product5' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT5_name
    WHEN 'product6' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT6_name
    WHEN 'product7' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT7_name
    WHEN 'product8' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT8_name
    WHEN 'product9' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT9_name
    END)
,'UNRESTRICTED','NEWNAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
UPPER(CASE table.productnames 
    WHEN 'product1' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT1_name
    WHEN 'product2' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT2_name
    WHEN 'product3' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT3_name 
    WHEN 'product4' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT4_name
    WHEN 'product5' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT5_name
    WHEN 'product6' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT6_name
    WHEN 'product7' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT7_name
    WHEN 'product8' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT8_name
    WHEN 'product9' THEN TABLE.SOMEPRODUCT9_name
    WHEN 'UNRESTRICTED' THEN 'NEWNAME'
END)
```

You don't need to add one line per case, please you should take a look at the documentation of the case statement first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx